# I am trying to extract the City from an address where everything is in one column, between last and second to last comma

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to extract the city from an address where everything is in one column, between last and second to last comma.

For example `Address` column contains

```
 LYNDEN COURT,CHARTWELL,HAMILTON,3210

 CNR DIXON & BANNISTER STREETS,MASTERTON,MASTERTON,5810

 3C,SHORT STREET,NEWMARKET,AUCKLAND,1023
```

As you can see, there is not always the same number of comma's. But I need to extract "Hamilton", "Masterton", and "Auckland" in these examples.

Want it as part of a select statement along with other fields in the same table.

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, but also using SSMS 2014 to access the server

Answer (score 1):

I probably over complicated this but you can try

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(50) = 'CNR DIXON & BANNISTER STREETS,MASTERTON,MASTERTON,5810'

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@var), CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(@var)) +1, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@var), CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(@var)) + 1) - CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(@var)) -1))
```

Comment: Awesome, works great!  I wasn't sure how to use the @var part so just put the field name in its stead and worked great. But when I run it on the whole table I get an error >Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.  But if I just run it YTD it works.  does that mean I have some bad data or is one of the values too long?

Comment: @EvanJones My guess would be there's some data that possibly doesn't have 2 commas or any commas which would make the length argument negative.